# Website's logo not getting displayed

Tags: html, css, case-sensitive, filepath, graphical-logo

I am working on a [website](http://stop4gifts.com/). I have uploaded a logo for the site. The logo displays fine when I run it on my PC, but when I upload the file online using FileZilla, the logo does not get displayed but only the alt text is displayed. I have double checked the code and I am almost sure that my code is fine. Here it is,

```
  <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html" title="Stop4Gifts"><img src="uploads/logo.png" alt="Stop4Gifts"/> </a></h1>
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: did you browse the image path in a address bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means your image may not be present, or has different path/name on server. If this is not the case, do check that it is not `logo.PNG` and also refresh the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with @TiddBFisher, the server is case-sensitive and logo.png will not work, but logo.PNG does. Try changing the extension on the file and re-uploading. Make sure to delete the old one with the upper-case extension.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. I did not knew that the server was case sensitive. +1 to you and all others who suggested it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check case on all files and file paths. I usually make everything lowercase in this type of situation.

Comment: Yes, this is what I also ensure, for all types of image, coding files and directories on Linux!

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

- check the image file did transfer successfully to the location you are expecting it at.
- image files should be transferred in binary mode when using ftp.
- some operating systems use case-sensitive file names - check the case of your file name and all references to it.

Answer (score 1):

i checked your site, there is no such a image [http://stop4gifts.com/uploads/logo.png] [right click on Stop4Gifts , and click view image] , may be it's .PNG?

Answer (score 1):

Issue in your extension, need to change .png to .PNG

```
<h1 id="logo">
  <a href="index.html" title="Stop4Gifts">
    <img src="uploads/logo.PNG" alt="Stop4Gifts"/> 
  </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: I would suggest other way round. Change all images/files to lowercase. And follow this rule forever!

Answer (score -1):

I recently uploaded a website on the internet using filezila. I have uploaded a logo for the site. The logo displays fine when I run it on my PC, but when I upload the file using FileZilla, the logo does not get displayed but only the alt text is displayed. All the styling displays fine accept for the head and logo.

heres the html and css code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/css.css" >
<img src="../img/beFluent1.jpg" alt="beFluent1logo" />
```